# Android Source Code (any version) compatible for Xilinx ZC 706

Tags: android, kernel, android-source, xilinx, zynq

I need android source code compatible for Xilinx ZC706 board. Please give me a link of a repository from where I can download. Any version is okay.

Also any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Sazal

Answer (score 0):

IVeia has a git repo for android on zynq but it is quiet old : [LINK](http://git.iveia.com/?p=xilinx/android/kernel/zynq.git;a=summary)

There are some blogs/wiki that might help you to get started. Most of them are for the zc702 board or zedboard but you might find some usefull information there.

- http://svenand.blogdrive.com/archive/200.html
- http://elinux.org/Zedboard_Android
- http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Android+On+Zynq+Getting+Started+Guide
- http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Android+4.2.2+On+Zynq+Getting+Started+Guide
- https://github.com/cambridgehackers/zynq-android4/wiki